# c#, server-client desktop application, using http/https ports for communication with high amount of data

Tags: c#, network-protocols

I have been looking around the internet to see what protocols are available for the client/server communication. I'm currently not able to find a durable solution for my problem, maybe looking the wrong places ?

The problem in short is that today I have a desktop `C#`, `WPF` application that communicates with a `C#` server application using `WCF` and TCP on dedicated ports. However, the use of TCP requires that external users needs to open the specific ports in their companies firewall to be able to use the application. This proves to be a bigger challenge than expected and therefor I'm trying to find if there are other ways to perform the communication.

I looked at `websockets` and `signalr` which uses HTTP(S), however I need at protocol that supports large amounts (sometimes 10MB at startup) of data transfer, which they don't seem to do well?

*In short:*

- I need a protocol for client/server  communication using the HTTP(s) channel and also performing well with larger amount of data.

This might be an impossible mission, due to lack of performance compared to TCP ?

Comment: HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 currently uses TCP/IP. HTTP/3 will implement QUIC running over UDP/IP which should allow faster transfers.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [GRPC](https://grpc.io/) - it still uses HTTP/2 but will reduce the message size compared to WCF.

Comment: @phuzi I haven't looked at GRPC, will do that right away. Thank you for the suggestion and comment.

Comment: If TCP connections are opened from servers to client I do not see the issues that companies would have.  Also if you are just downloading data use FTPS may be a reasonable alternative.  The FTPS could be initiated from server and not need a service running on server.

Comment: @jdweng I guess I'm missing some description. The client initiates communication to the server, this is a long lived rich client that does a lot of requests to the server depending on what the user is doing. However, almost all functionality in the client requires data from the server.

Comment: What's wrong with a standard `HttpListener` listening on TCP443

Comment: @Charlieface Isn't that just meant for http request, I wouldn't expect it to have good performance in a client server environment ?

Comment: `HttpListener` is meant for server applications. Why wouldn't you expect it to have good performance? It might need a bit of tuning, such as `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` and fully streamed results, as well as correct usage of `Task.Run` and `await`, but it should be fine in terms of performance. You can pass a byte array or `FileStream`, it does not have to be Base64 encoded.

Comment: Many standard algorithms uses multiple connections which can be combinations of http and TCP.  The TCP client/server may be opposite from http connection.  I would check with your users to see if they have any standard protocol ports already allowed to go through firewall.  Here is a standard list of ports : Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers